# nginx : meaning of "expires 30d"

Tags: django, nginx, static

**[Update]**

**expires 30d** : Static file cache expires after 30 days on **client's browser**

**etag on** : This attribute is only available after version **1.3.3**. Each static file has 'etag **hash value**'. Client will make a request for server if the **static file is changed** (Even though not expired yet).

===================================================================

Here's a sample of nginx.conf file for django project

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hostname.com;

    ...

    location /static/ {          # STATIC_URL
        alias /path/to/static/;  # STATIC_ROOT
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {           # MEDIA_URL
        alias /path/to/media/;   # MEDIA_ROOT
        expires 30d;
    }

    ...
}
```

In this code, what is the meaning of "***expires 30d***" ?

(1) static, media file would be deleted after 30 days, and manage.py will regenerate them automatically.

(2) static, media file would be deleted after 30 days, and I should type `manage.py collectstatic` manually.

Similarly, I wonder the meaning of "***expires max***"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds two HTTP headers to the responses (`Expires` and `Cache-Control`). Those headers are used by the browsers to cache content, avoid doing the same requests for static content each time a page is loaded.

`expires 30d` means that all content in static and media folders will be cached by browsers during 30 days, but nothing will be deleted and you won't need to regenerate anything in the server.

`expires max` set the `Expires` header to the value "Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT", and  the `Cache-Control` to 10 years.

See the nginx documentation for more details: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

For more info about HTTP caching see http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that it is cache settings for the client browser, not the server side. Thanks for your kind answer ! :)